# Is it able to call a controller from another controller in mvc?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I would like to ask if able to call a controller inside the controller?

E.g

```
class ControllerUserUser extends Controller { 
    .......
}

class ControllerUserWoo extends Controller { 
    How do i call the ControllerUserUser from here? 
    Or it is not recommend to do so?

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended. But you can call a different model/helper (a place to store various functions) out of that controller.

Comment: Models and helpers are classes/objects not places :-).